# Weird javascript syntax error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Firefox I received a weird syntax error, as this is not trivial, and an interesting syntax error I'd like to post here because I don't know it's happening.

Should file this as a bug report?

I was testing some scripts from here: [here](http://glennstovall.com/blog/2013/06/27/angularjs-an-overview/)

It gave me a syntax error. `SyntaxError: invalid label at line 5`.

```
app.directive("alertable", function()
{
    return 
    {
        restrict : "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) 
        {
            element.bind("click", function() 
            {
                alert(attrs.message);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And this one, don't:

```
app.directive("alertable", function()
{
    return { // fix???
        restrict : "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) 
        {
            element.bind("click", function() 
            {
                alert(attrs.message);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behavior is by design.

Semicolons in Javascript are optional.  ([ASI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi))
The parser inserts an implicit semicolon after the `return` line, and assumes that the `{` begins a code block.  (like after an `if` or `for`)

The first line in that code block is not actually valid code, so you get that error.

This happens because `return` is a valid statement both with and without an operand.

Similarly, the code

```
return
4;
```

Is parsed as `return; 4;`.

Comment: Thanks for enlightment, I never heard before about "ASI". Good to know. Now i shall code better.